# How can I Store a WebSocket Error in a Variable

Tags: javascript, websocket, error-handling, console

Hey I have a websocket I am trying to connect, but I get an error in return. I haven't coded much in javascript so I would appreciate it if someone wrote a snippet of the code I am trying to put here.

Anyway, what I am trying to achieve is to store this error in the console into a variable. Not necessarily the whole thing, but only the part where it says 'ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT'.

```
var connection = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.2.1:80');
```

It gives me an error in 'CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT' error. I have posted a screenshot, just incase if anyone would want to see.

[image]

Comment: Please post code and error message as text

Comment: I have put a screenshot :)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Oh .. I'll put the code with comments :)

Answer (score 0):

[onerror](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/onerror)

```
webSocket = new WebSocket("/foo/bar");

webSocket.onerror = function(event) { //Informations about the error are in event
  console.error("WebSocket error observed:", event);
};
```